# double to int conversion (*10 work, 100 loss of precision)

Tags: c++, type-conversion, int, double

Question related to [Why does this double to int conversion not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852815/why-does-this-double-to-int-conversion-not-work)

```
    #include <iostream>
    int main()
    {
        double x = 4.10;
        double j = x * 100;

        int k = (int) j;

        std::cout << k;
     }

     Output: 409
```

BUT with 10 instead of 100 :

```
    #include <iostream>
    int main()
    {
        double x = 4.10;
        double j = x * 10;

        int k = (int) j;

        std::cout << k;
     }

     Output: 41
```

Since the value actually stored is something like 4.099999... I would expect to get 40 because of truncate and not 41 which is the exact value.

What happened ?

Comment: FWIW, `* 1000` brings you back to 4100

Comment: look at the value of `j` before making it an `int`

Comment: IEEE floating point operations round. Since you don't have exact precision that could go up or down depending on the actual numbers involved.

Comment: Well it was obvious... thanks!