# A curious result about conversion between double and int in C++

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

My Problem:

Try to figure out the result of the following C++ snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double a = 5.1;
    int b = a * 100;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    double c = 6.1;
    int d = c * 100;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

On Windows, I compiled and run the above code with VS2008 SP1 and get:

```
509
610
```

While on Linux, I compiled and run the same code with g++ and get:

```
509
609
```

What is the problem of the code?

Sorry I have tried to figure a title for the problem thus I could have searched around. However, I can't name this problem, so I directly present it here.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Only the billionth duplicate of this question...

Comment: I'm so glad this link is on the tag wiki: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: 509 610 on Windows, 509 609 on Linux. Does this finally proof Windows is better than Linux?

Comment: `5.1` isn't exactly 5.1.  It's actually 5.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375.

Comment: This is why the result seems so weird.  The `int`-to-`double` conversion always rounds down to the floor instead of the closest integer.

Comment: @StephenCanon: Why do you think a compiler has to round it down?

Comment: @MSalters: assuming correct default rounding, which is the case with most sane compilers.

Comment: @StephenCanon: That's not true. 5.1 is always 5.1. But `a` is not necessarily 5.1!

Comment: @KerrekSB: The number 5.1 is always 5.1.  The double-precision literal `5.1` is not 5.1.

Comment: @StephenCanon: OK, fair enough.

Comment: @StephenCanon: I can't find that in the standard. C99 is explicitly different: "the result is either the nearest representable value, or the larger or smaller representable value immediately adjacent to the nearest representable value, chosen in an **implementation-defined manner.**"

Comment: @MSalters: it's not in the C or C++ standard (beyond the text you identified); it is, however, in the IEEE-754 standard which the implementations in question here generally attempt to adhere to (hence "assuming").

Comment: @StephenCanon: Can't find that either; the IEEE-754 wording on _external character sequence_ suggests that you use 9 digits to get a guaranteed 32 bits value. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Character_representation

Comment: @MSalters: IEEE-754 clause 5.12: "translation-time conversion of constants in program text from external character sequences to supported formats, in the absence of other specification in the program text, **shall** use this standard’s default rounding direction and language-defined exception handling."

Comment: possible duplicate of [strange double to int conversion behavior in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860783/strange-double-to-int-conversion-behavior-in-c)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Thanks a lot! And please note that it is declared that I have tried to figure a name of the problem thus it could be searched before being posted here. :)

Comment: @stoneyang: Just stick around this website for about a week, and you'll see what I mean :-) (And while you're at it, you can answer some questions and earn some badges! Yumm...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`double` is *not* an exact type, as you can see by applying the [`std::numeric_limits` typetrait](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_exact):

```
#include <limits>

static_assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::is_exact == false);
```

Thus computations involving doubles are only approximate, and there is nothing wrong about what you observe.

*There is no problem with your code.*

Comment: Weird, I never knew that existed. Thanks for the proof tool.

Comment: Then again, `3/2` isn't exact either. It's just inexact in the first fractional bit instead of the 53rd.

Comment: This answer doesn't really explain the difference in behaviour for the two compilers / system, which seems to be at the heart of the question. `double` is not exact, yes, but it doesn't mean it is OK for it to behave differently when rounded.

Comment: @J.N.: The problem isn't with the rounding. The problem is that we can't know the value of `a`, since it is only *approximately* 5.1, in an implementation-defined way.

Comment: @MSalters: `3/2` is exactly `1` :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB : iso `double` guarantees 15 digits of precisions from string litterals, I can't see what's implementation defined here; even if there is an inherent loss of precision by the multiplication, it can't be that big. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @J.N.: Let's make a toy example. Suppose a fictional type only promised five decimal digits of precision. The literal `5.2`, evaluated as that type, might be either `5.20003` or `5.19997`, in some arcane architecture, and that would be entirely compliant. There's no preference for either, and both are the same when rounded to five significant digits. Yet multiplying by 100 and truncating gives different results.

Comment: @J.N. : It doesn't matter how big the loss of precision is, if it happens exactly at the edge value for rounding. In this case, the mathematical expression `5.1 * 100.0` has to be rounded to integer `510`, but `(5.1-ε) * 10.00` has to be rounded to 509 for ε>0

Answer (score 2):

In general, with double (and float) being binary, you can only ever make precise representations of fractions of powers of 2. Thus, if the decimal part is only made up of terms like 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 etc. a float or double will be exact (unless you run into precision problems, of course).

Now, "0.1" is 1/10, which is actually 1/2 * 1/5. 5 is not a power of two, thus "0.1" can't be represented in binary, it can only be approximated.

Comment: There exist decimal float types (which are implemented on binary hardware) which *can* represent 0.1 exactly. There's nothing inherently bad about binary. It just comes down to a matter of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

`double` to `int` conversion is done by truncation unless otherwise specified. In your case, due to loss of precisions while rounding the numbers (and a small amount of bad luck as noted by MSalters since this only happens near some "edge" values).

Here are few possible reasons for the difference in behaviour between compilers/OS:

- Optimizations: some compilers implement compile time floating operation with infinite precision. Since your code is simple it is possible for the compiler to do the computation at compile time with infinite precision. (Have you checked the generated ASM code ?)
- Using different internal representation. Since you are running windows you are using an x86 or an x86-64 CPU that implements floating points with more than 64 bits see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) for some details.
- Use of a different architecture entirely (are both your OS 64 bit ?)

Answer (score 1):

As one of the rules of *The elements of programming styles* by Kernighan and Plauger stated.

> `10.0` times `0.1` is hardly ever `1.0`

Meaning that floats don't behave like mathematical real numbers. There is a standard (IEEE 754) how you can implement floats but its not part of the C standard but only in C#.